# R: How to use RegEx to search multiple words using a disjunction

Tags: r, regex

Let me explain what I want to do. I have a corpus data (15 M words) about a political debate and I want to find the co-ocurrence of two terms within, say, 10k words.

I create two vectors of positions of two terms: "false" and "law".

```
false.v <- c(133844, 133880, 145106, 150995, 152516, 152557, 153697, 155507)   
law.v <- c(48064, 155644, 251315, 297303, 323417, 349576, 368052, 543487)
```

Then I want to gather them on a matrix to see the co-ocurrence using the 'outer' function. The positions are taken from the same corpus, so I'm creating a matrix of differences:

```
distances <- outer(false.v, law.v, "-")
```

To make this easier to read lets name them:

```
rownames(distances) <- paste0("False", false.v)  
colnames(distances) <- paste0("Law", law.v)
```

Okay, so we have the matrix ready. To find which pairs of positions were within 10000 words of each other I just run:

```
abs(distances) <= 10000
```

So I have to identify those moments in the political debate where there is a greater frequency of those co-occurences. Here comes the problem. I have to do it with more than a pair of words (In fact with 5 pair of words or so), so it would be great if I just could search multiple words instead of two pair of words at a time. So instead searching "false" and "law", search "false OR lie OR whatever" and "law OR money OR whatever". I guess I have to use RegEx for this task, isn't it? I just tried everything and nothing worked.

The example I just gave is a simplification. The command I use to search words is creating a vector out of the corpus:

```
positions.law.v <- which(C1.corpus.v == "law")
```

Soo it would be great if I can just use something like

```
which(C1.corpus.v == "law OR money OR prison OR ...")

which(C1.corpus.v == "false OR lie OR country OR ...")
```

It's like telling R "hey, give me the co-ocurrence positions of any possible combination between the first row of words (law or money or prison...) and the second one (false or lie or country...). I hope I'm explaining it in a clear way. I'm sorry for the language mistakes. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
```

I have an extended answer here as well, but it could be as simple as:

```
mywords = c("law", "money", "prison", "false", "lie", "country")

which(C1.corpus.v %in% mywords)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!! That's a possible solution indeed. I just created two vectors (one for each first term of the pair of words) and used it with that command `which(C1.corpus.v %in% mywords)`. The rest is the same procedure I just followed, this is, using the `outer()` function to gather those vectors into a matrix and then searching the co-ocurrences of those vectors. So far so good! It would be nice to use RegEx to search things like `constituti(on|onal)` as @Konrad suggested me, but I'm not sure how to make it. This is my first post and damn, you guys are awesome!

Comment: @Descartes glad I can help. I'm not familiar with @KONRAD's `fcm` solution. But, I've used `library(quanteda)` quite a bit and it has a feature to notice root words, especially for words like `constitutional`. Check out https://quanteda.io/reference/tokens_wordstem.html

Comment: Thank you!! Ok, last time I ask and I stop bothering you. Do you know how can I search expressions like "not true" or "it is false" in a vector? I have created `terms = c("false", "untrue", "blabla")` to search them in the entire corpus, but it seems it doesn't allow whitespaces. Ouch. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @Descartes I believe ngrams are the solution to this. Hope it helps: http://quanteda.io/reference/tokens_ngrams.html

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(quanteda)
```

I'll use the election manifestos of 9 UK political parties from 2010:

```
data_char_ukimmig2010
```

Create a tokens object (there are lots of settings - check out https://quanteda.io/)

```
mytoks <- data_char_ukimmig2010 %>%
  char_tolower() %>%
  tokens()

mywords = c("law", "money", "prison", "false", "lie", "country")
```

`kwic` "return[s] a list of a keyword supplied by the user in its immediate context, identifying the source text and the word index number within the source text" [source](https://quanteda.io/reference/kwic.html)

```
mykwic <- kwic(mytoks, mywords)
```

A `kwic` builds a data frame with various features, one of which is the integer value starting position of your keywords (because you can use it to look for phrases):

```
mykwic$from
```

Gives us:

```
> mykwic$from
 [1]  130  438  943 1259 1281 1305 1339 1356 1743 1836 1859 2126 2187 2443 2546 2640 2763 2952 3186 3270  179    8  201
[24]  343  354  391  498   16  131  552   14   29  388   80  306  487  507
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is slightly more sophisticated than using regex. For instance, you may be willing to include `law`, `legal` and `legislation` in one group but do not include `lawless`. Regex like `\blaw.*\b` wouldn't help you much. In effect, you are interested in:

- Creating feature co-occurrence matrix
- Incorporating the semantic proximity of the words

## Feature co-occurrence matrix

This is a well-established task and I would encourage you to use a tested solution like the [`fcm`](https://rdrr.io/cran/quanteda/man/fcm.html) function. To introduce an example from the documentation:

```
txt <- "A D A C E A D F E B A C E D"
fcm(txt, context = "window", window = 2)
fcm(txt, context = "window", count = "weighted", window = 3)
fcm(txt, context = "window", count = "weighted", window = 3, 
             weights = c(3, 2, 1), ordered = TRUE, tri = FALSE)
```

## Your regex

To suggest a solution to your particular problem. This:

```
which(C1.corpus.v == "law OR money OR prison OR ...")
```

where

```
C1.corpus.v <- c("law", "word", "something","legal", "stuff")
```

you could do

```
grep(
    pattern = paste("legal", "law", "som.*", sep = "|"),
    x = C1.corpus.v,
    perl = TRUE,
    value = FALSE
)
```

where `sep = "|"` serves as your `...OR...`. IMHO, this is not what you want as it does not address semantic similarity. I would suggest you have a look at some of the good tutorials that are available on the net <sup>1,2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Taylor Arnold and Lauren Tilton [*Basic Text Processing in R*](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/basic-text-processing-in-r)
<sup>2</sup> Islam, Aminul & Inkpen, Diana. (2008). [*Semantic Text Similarity Using Corpus-Based Word Similarity and String Similarity*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220345072_Semantic_Text_Similarity_Using_Corpus-Based_Word_Similarity_and_String_Similarity). TKDD. 2. 10.1145/1376815.1376819.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!! I think that `grep()` function is going to help me a lot. So if I understood it I can use the command `pattern = paste("word/s", sep = "|"),` to search things like "constituti(on|onal)", right? i.e., `pattern = paste("law", "money", "constituti(on|onal)", "millions?", sep = "|")` ?

Comment: @Descartes You would rather use `constitution.*|law.*`, as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/SQzF9v/4).

Comment: That's nice! Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @Descartes No problem, feel free to vote up the answer.